# Parse JSON File in Golang

Tags: json, go

I have JSON File

```
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "ac691afd-f987-47ca-82d3-dae2a367e3df",
        "name": "ParseGo",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "Gogo",
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://www.google.com/",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "www",
                        "google",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        ""
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Golang",
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [],
                "url": {
                    "raw": ""
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Hide Pool!",
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [],
                "url": {
                    "raw": ""
                }
            },
            "response": []
        }
    ],
    "protocolProfileBehavior": {}
}
```

and i want parse this, i want see in terminal name and method. How i can this?

i try this but not work( help pls. I try use this code

```
package main
{
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

type Student struct {
    Name     string
    Standard int `json:"Standard"`
}

func main() {
    // open the file pointer
    studentFile, err := os.Open("data.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer studentFile.Close()

    var studentDecoder *json.Decoder = json.NewDecoder(studentFile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var studentList []Student

    err = studentDecoder.Decode(&studentList)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for i, student := range studentList {
        fmt.Println("Student", i+1)
        fmt.Println("Student name:", student.Name)
        fmt.Println("Student standard:", student.Standard)
    }
}
```

I'm not strong in Go, how can I modify the code for my task and is it possible? if i try this code i have this error
2020/11/05 13:29:54 json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []main.Student
exit status 1

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at this https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/ online tool that easily generate a struct starting from a json files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to do something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

type Data struct {
    Item []Item `json:"item"`
}

type Item struct {
    Name    string  `json:"name"`
    Request Request `json:"request"`
}

type Request struct {
    Method string `json:"method"`
}

func main() {
    filename := "/path/to/your_file.json"
    jsonFile, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("failed to open json file: %s, error: %v", filename, err)
        return
    }
    defer jsonFile.Close()

    jsonData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("failed to read json file, error: %v", err)
        return
    }

    data := Data{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &data); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("failed to unmarshal json file, error: %v", err)
        return
    }

    // Print
    for _, item := range data.Item {
        fmt.Printf("Name: %s, Method: %s \n", item.Name, item.Request.Method)
    }
}
```

Result must look like this:

```
Name: Gogo, Method: GET
Name: Golang, Method: GET
Name: Hide Pool!, Method: GET
```

Comment: NIT: Check the first `err` value before deferring `json.Close`.

Comment: @Olshansk Makes sense, thx!